# Percentage of samples within two folds of each other in r data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, classification

I am having a data frame of 6 variables. For each pair of variable, I want to find out the percentage of observations classified into different categories based on certain condition applying over two variables.
my data is given below. In this, I want to find out what percentage of observations (between variables 1,4 & 2,5 & 3,6) are within 2 fold of each other, 3 fold of each other, 4 fold of each other and more than 4 fold of each other.

```
dput(LPBEMab25072019Negative)
structure(list(LogGPSO = c(1.20411998265592, 1.04139268515823, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
2.25767857486918, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.95424250943932, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, NA, 2.25767857486918, 1.04139268515823, 
1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
2.25767857486918, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 
3.01029995663981, 2.25767857486918, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.95424250943932, 1.34242268082221, 1.20411998265592, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.95424250943932, 
1.34242268082221, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.34242268082221, 2.55870857053317, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 2.25767857486918, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.20411998265592, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 1.34242268082221, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.50514997831991, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.36172783601759, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.80617997398389, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944), LogGPSA = c(NA, 
NA, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.95424250943932, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, NA, 
1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.20411998265592, 3.01029995663981, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.20411998265592, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.36172783601759, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.36172783601759, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.20411998265592, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.36172783601759, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944), LogGPSAsia1 = c(NA, NA, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.95424250943932, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, NA, 1.95424250943932, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 3.01029995663981, 
1.34242268082221, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.34242268082221, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.50514997831991, 0.903089986991944, 
1.34242268082221, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.34242268082221, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.20411998265592, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 
0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.36172783601759, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.36172783601759, 
1.36172783601759, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.36172783601759, 
0.903089986991944, 1.50514997831991, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944), LogMabO = c(1.20411998265592, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 1.80617997398389, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.80617997398389, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 1.20411998265592, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 
1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.20411998265592, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944), LogMabA = c(NA, NA, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 
1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.20411998265592, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 1.34242268082221, 
1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.20411998265592, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944), LogMabAsia1 = c(NA, NA, 1.34242268082221, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.80617997398389, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.80617997398389, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.50514997831991, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.50514997831991, 
1.20411998265592, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.80617997398389, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.50514997831991, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.50514997831991, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 1.34242268082221, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.903089986991944, 
1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 1.65321251377534, 1.65321251377534, 1.20411998265592, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 1.20411998265592, 
1.20411998265592, 1.65321251377534, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 
1.04139268515823, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.20411998265592, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 1.34242268082221, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04139268515823, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944)), row.names = c(NA, 
-198L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

for example

```
between Variables   1&4    2&5   3&6
within  2 fold       95     90    92
within  3 fold        3     5     5
within  4 fold        2     4     3
more than 4 fold      1     1     0
```

I am new to writing codes. help in this analysis is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is a fold, how do you know if a pair of observations are within 2 fold of eachother, and what is the numerator and denomninator for the percentage you want to calculate?

Comment: I want to compare the value of one variable with the value of another variable for one observation (for example row number 1 value of LogGPSO is16 and value of LogMabO is 16, which indicates it is within 2 fold of each other). if the values are falling within 2 fold of each other then I consider that observation as belonging to within 2 fold category. count of these cases are numerator and total number of observations in each variable is denominator.